# My Batis Error When the volume of sending parameter is big

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, amazon-redshift, ibatis

Environment

```
org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1102-jdbc41
org.mybatis:mybatis:3.2.7
```

the query is  like below. my app is connecting to AWS RedShift

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE
 <foreach item="item" collection="lists" open="(" close=")" separator=" OR ">
        (xxx BETWEEN #{item.From} AND #{item.To})
 </foreach>
```

if the length of the parameter, lists is too big(over 3000), mybatis get some error.

```
2015-11-07 12:46:26,672 [main] ERROR Main - org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
### The error may exist in com/xxx/sql/sql_redshift.xml
### The error may involve com.xxx.sql.findXXXs-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
```

I think generated query sending to RedShift is too big to send.
Is there a good way to avoid this issue?

FYI
output query is like this

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE
    (
    (xxx BETWEEN 2 AND 5) OR
    (xxx BETWEEN 9 AND 12) OR
    (xxx BETWEEN 15 AND 20) OR
    (xxx BETWEEN 30 AND 59) OR
    )
```

Comment: You are querying from 3000 table?

Comment: its my mistake. I fixed above query.